# show welcome message only on index.php [CI]

Tags: codeigniter, continuous-integration

I make custom welcome message in codeigniter script, but i want show only on index.php

I have

```
                <div class="welcome">
            <?php echo getConfigSetting('config_welcome') ?>
                           </div>
```

This message show in header,on all page. I want show only on homepage (index.php)

I already tried this code but give me a blank page

```
<?php if( $this->uri->segment(1) == 'home' || $this->uri->segment(1) = '' ): ?>
```

Affordable Business Websites Done Fast…
                                "Just find a website you like and we will customize it to your business needs, easy as 123!"
                                Start Search

```
                                                        </div>

                    </div>
```

Any sugestion?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you could try to use the CI helper URL and grab the first segment of the url to check whta page we are on.

example:

```
<?php if( $this->uri->segment(1) == 'home' || $this->uri->segment(1) = '' ): ?>
  <div class="welcome">
    <?php echo getConfigSetting('config_welcome') ?>
  </div>
<?php endIf; ?>
```

of course you would want to change the "home" to the name of your homepage name you see in the url, or the default controller/method name.

You will also want to make sure you autoload the **url**_helper in the config/autoload.

Comment: i enter this but give blank page.